# Determine the initial speed and launch angle of a projectile from its trajectory

Tags: physics, modeling

I have the coordinates `{x,y}` needed to plot the trajectory of a projectile, which are given below:

```
{{0., 0.}, {0.808394, 0.315251}, {1.61679, 0.624132}, {2.42518, 
  0.926645}, {3.23358, 1.22279}, {4.04197, 1.51257}, {4.85036, 
  1.79597}, {5.65876, 2.07301}, {6.46715, 2.34368}, {7.27555, 
  2.60798}, {8.08394, 2.86591}, {8.89233, 3.11748}, {9.70073, 
  3.36267}, {10.5091, 3.6015}, {11.3175, 3.83396}, {12.1259, 
  4.06004}, {12.9343, 4.27976}, {13.7427, 4.49312}, {14.5511, 
  4.7001}, {15.3595, 4.90071}, {16.1679, 5.09496}, {16.9763, 
  5.28283}, {17.7847, 5.46434}, {18.5931, 5.63948}, {19.4015, 
  5.80825}, {20.2098, 5.97065}, {21.0182, 6.12669}, {21.8266, 
  6.27635}, {22.635, 6.41965}, {23.4434, 6.55657}, {24.2518, 
  6.68713}, {25.0602, 6.81132}, {25.8686, 6.92914}, {26.677, 
  7.04059}, {27.4854, 7.14568}, {28.2938, 7.24439}, {29.1022, 
  7.33674}, {29.9106, 7.42272}, {30.719, 7.50233}, {31.5274, 
  7.57557}, {32.3358, 7.64244}, {33.1442, 7.70294}, {33.9525, 
  7.75707}, {34.7609, 7.80484}, {35.5693, 7.84624}, {36.3777, 
  7.88126}, {37.1861, 7.90992}, {37.9945, 7.93221}, {38.8029, 
  7.94813}, {39.6113, 7.95769}, {40.4197, 7.96087}, {41.2281, 
  7.95769}, {42.0365, 7.94813}, {42.8449, 7.93221}, {43.6533, 
  7.90992}, {44.4617, 7.88126}, {45.2701, 7.84624}, {46.0785, 
  7.80484}, {46.8869, 7.75707}, {47.6952, 7.70294}, {48.5036, 
  7.64244}, {49.312, 7.57557}, {50.1204, 7.50233}, {50.9288, 
  7.42272}, {51.7372, 7.33674}, {52.5456, 7.24439}, {53.354, 
  7.14568}, {54.1624, 7.04059}, {54.9708, 6.92914}, {55.7792, 
  6.81132}, {56.5876, 6.68713}, {57.396, 6.55657}, {58.2044, 
  6.41965}, {59.0128, 6.27635}, {59.8212, 6.12669}, {60.6295, 
  5.97065}, {61.4379, 5.80825}, {62.2463, 5.63948}, {63.0547, 
  5.46434}, {63.8631, 5.28283}, {64.6715, 5.09496}, {65.4799, 
  4.90071}, {66.2883, 4.7001}, {67.0967, 4.49312}, {67.9051, 
  4.27976}, {68.7135, 4.06004}, {69.5219, 3.83396}, {70.3303, 
  3.6015}, {71.1387, 3.36267}, {71.9471, 3.11748}, {72.7555, 
  2.86591}, {73.5639, 2.60798}, {74.3722, 2.34368}, {75.1806, 
  2.07301}, {75.989, 1.79597}, {76.7974, 1.51257}, {77.6058, 
  1.22279}, {78.4142, 0.926645}, {79.2226, 0.624132}, {80.031, 
  0.315251}, {80.8394, 0}}
```

I then make a list plot. How do I obtain the initial speed `vo` and the angle `theta` given `G = -9.81`

[image]

Comment: Have you seen `Fit[]`?

Comment: Expanding on @J.M. 's comment, you can use the analytical equation that describes the motion of a projectile as a function of `V0` and `theta` as a model for one of the fitting functions (`Fit`, `FindFit`, `NonlinearModelFit`). You will then obtain estimates for `V0` and `theta` that best fit your data points. As it stands, though, this question is likely to be closed since the usage patterns of the fitting functions are directly found in the documentation. You may want to try this approach on your own, then share any problems you encounter here.

Comment: Presumably you are aware of the parabolic nature of the trajectory; hence the suggestion to use `Fit[]` on your points and then determine parameters from there.

Comment: will try this approach. Thank You @MarcoB

Comment: thank you @J. M.♦ will try it first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can solve the problem with fit as J.M. suggests in his comment, you can also solve it directly by applying the Galilean equations of motion.

1. Find the range and maximum height of the projectile from the data.

   ```
   g = 9.81;

   data = 
    {{0., 0.}, {0.808394, 0.315251}, {1.61679, 0.624132}, {2.42518, 0.926645}, 
     {3.23358, 1.22279}, {4.04197, 1.51257}, {4.85036, 1.79597}, {5.65876, 2.07301}, 
     {6.46715, 2.34368}, {7.27555, 2.60798}, {8.08394, 2.86591}, {8.89233, 3.11748}, 
     {9.70073, 3.36267}, {10.5091, 3.6015}, {11.3175, 3.83396}, {12.1259, 4.06004}, 
     {12.9343, 4.27976}, {13.7427, 4.49312}, {14.5511, 4.7001}, {15.3595, 4.90071}, 
     {16.1679, 5.09496}, {16.9763, 5.28283}, {17.7847, 5.46434}, {18.5931, 5.63948}, 
     {19.4015, 5.80825}, {20.2098, 5.97065}, {21.0182, 6.12669}, {21.8266, 6.27635}, 
     {22.635, 6.41965}, {23.4434, 6.55657}, {24.2518, 6.68713}, {25.0602, 6.81132}, 
     {25.8686, 6.92914}, {26.677, 7.04059}, {27.4854, 7.14568}, {28.2938, 7.24439}, 
     {29.1022, 7.33674}, {29.9106, 7.42272}, {30.719, 7.50233}, {31.5274, 7.57557}, 
     {32.3358, 7.64244}, {33.1442, 7.70294}, {33.9525, 7.75707}, {34.7609, 7.80484}, 
     {35.5693, 7.84624}, {36.3777, 7.88126}, {37.1861, 7.90992}, {37.9945, 7.93221}, 
     {38.8029, 7.94813}, {39.6113, 7.95769}, {40.4197, 7.96087}, {41.2281, 7.95769}, 
     {42.0365, 7.94813}, {42.8449, 7.93221}, {43.6533, 7.90992}, {44.4617, 7.88126}, 
     {45.2701, 7.84624}, {46.0785, 7.80484}, {46.8869, 7.75707}, {47.6952, 7.70294}, 
     {48.5036, 7.64244}, {49.312, 7.57557}, {50.1204, 7.50233}, {50.9288, 7.42272}, 
     {51.7372, 7.33674}, {52.5456, 7.24439}, {53.354, 7.14568}, {54.1624, 7.04059}, 
     {54.9708, 6.92914}, {55.7792, 6.81132}, {56.5876, 6.68713}, {57.396, 6.55657}, 
     {58.2044, 6.41965}, {59.0128, 6.27635}, {59.8212, 6.12669}, {60.6295, 5.97065}, 
     {61.4379, 5.80825}, {62.2463, 5.63948}, {63.0547, 5.46434}, {63.8631, 5.28283}, 
     {64.6715, 5.09496}, {65.4799, 4.90071}, {66.2883, 4.7001}, {67.0967, 4.49312}, 
     {67.9051, 4.27976}, {68.7135, 4.06004}, {69.5219, 3.83396}, {70.3303, 3.6015}, 
     {71.1387, 3.36267}, {71.9471, 3.11748}, {72.7555, 2.86591}, {73.5639, 2.60798}, 
     {74.3722, 2.34368}, {75.1806, 2.07301}, {75.989, 1.79597}, {76.7974, 1.51257}, 
     {77.6058, 1.22279}, {78.4142, 0.926645}, {79.2226, 0.624132}, {80.031, 0.315251}, 
     {80.8394, 0}};

   {xmax, ymax} = Max /@ Transpose[data]
   ```

   > `{80.8394, 7.96087}`
2. The time of flight is twice the time it would take the projectile to drop from the its maximum height to the ground.

   ```
   tFlight = 2. Max[t /. Solve[ymax == .5 g t^2, t]]
   ```

   > `2.54795`
3. The x-component of the motion is linear, so x-component of the velocity at any time just

   ```
   vx = xmax/tFlight
   ```

   > `31.7272`
4. The initial y-component of the motion is same as the velocity the projectile would have when it hits the ground if dropped from height `ymax` -- which takes time `tFlight/2` -- so

   ```
   vy = g tFlight/2.
   ```

   > `12.4977`

Thus,

```
{vo, theta} = {Norm[{vx, vy}], ArcTan[vx, vy]/Degree}
```

> `{34.1, 21.5}`

where `theta` is given in degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could help

```
  g = -9.81;
  xmax = Max[path[[All, 1]]];(*Range*)
  ymax = Max[path[[All, 2]]];(*Height*)
  t = Sqrt[2*ymax/-g]; (*time for the flight*)
  Vy = -g t/2; (*Y component of the velocity at max hight*)
  Vx = xmax/(2 t);
  ListLinePlot[path]
```

Use the standard equations of motion for projectile. t, R, Vx, Vy etc.